# Unknown: failed to open stream:

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, server

I have three websites that are down namely http://brumdesign.xyz https://www.commsaxis.com https://www.thefloralfabriccompany.co.uk with the mainone being brumdesign.xyz and the other 2 as addon domains. each has the same problem namely....

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home22/commsa12/public_html/index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

the 2 addon domains did have wordpress which I have downloaded and backed-up and have uploaded a very simple Hello world index.php file to each. I have also duplicated one of the websites on a test domain to make sure that it's working fine there with ssl and php7 and to be sure it's nothing there causing the issues. You can see the testsite [here](https://testsite.brumdev.xyz/)

I have checked the nameservers and the dns settings are fully correct. Also there is not any .htaccess on those domains at all! I have tested on both php7 and now it's running php5.6

I think everything is covered but have I missed anything else out?
Many thanks

Comment: Do you realise that this path `/home22/commsa12/public_html/commsaxis.com/index.php` would be `www.site.com/commsaxis.com/index.php` ? (assuming public_html is the site root)

Comment: plus surely if you've reuploaded WP you shouldn't also manually edit the .htaccess file as this is something WP will sort out itself...

Comment: Yes i do realise that Martin. the commsaxis one is an addon domain and all I have in public_html is an index.php file there as the site root if that helps!

Comment: The site is now getting a 508 resource limit reached for some reason and I have also downgraded to php5.6 to see if that makes any difference! Weird that it was working perfectly fine 3 days ago though!

Comment: The first step to debug this, would be to replace index.php with a simple "Hello, world" script. From this, you can see, if it is the .htaccess or somewhere else in the script(s). Next, after restoring the original index.php, would be to consult the error.log, etc.

Comment: Hi Olaf, Thank you for that! I have already tried this and nothing is showing. weirdly the main domain http://brumdesign.xyz/ is coming up with the same results as the commsaxis one is simply an addon domain!

Comment: If you've already done the things we are suggesting, this implies your question is poorly written. You need to tell us everything you've tried so that we can give you a useful answer, otherwise we just waste our (and your) time suggesting things you know you've done and we *don't* know you've done. Please **EDIT** your question giving as much details as possible as to what you've tried to solve your issue and what results these trials achieved. thanks

Comment: Thanks @Martin I have edited the question and made it simpler. Basically I have deleted wordpress from each domain and uploaded a really simple index.php script also yes brumdesign.xyz is the public_html.